# How to kill all/particular background thread in Javafx?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, worker-thread

The application is having four **javafx** fxml-screens : login, home, profile and features. A lots of worker thread is created in various screens after login is done. When user is getting logout, the all worker thread except **Javafx-Application-Thread** should be cancelled.

Comment: So, where is the question mark(`?`) in the body of the post? Is there even a questions there?

Answer (score 2):

A convenient way to manage your worker threads is to use [the Executor framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).

**Example**:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

//  submit your JavaFX tasks and services 
executorService.shutdown();
//executorService.shutdownNow();
```

**More about Java and JavaFX concurrency:**

- [Worker Threading in JavaFX 2.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)
- [javafx.concurrent package docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html)
- [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is not any mechanism for kill any thread in javafx.
but y can cancel the particular thread using cancel() method.